# 556 circuit not working

Tags: timer, 555

I just got my 556 timers and I wired it up just like the 555 but now: it flashes one HighTime and stays off then...

I used this calculator and basic diagram: http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator

And changed it to fit the 556:
[image: 556 Schematic]

You guys have any idea why this is not working?

(P.S.: I used green wires here if lines are overlapping)

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't look too close to your circuit, but I think, the 556 doesn't work at 3V. Which kind of 556 do you have?

Comment: Oh; yes; I added it to 5V (WeMos D1Mini) - just did it wrong when I created  the schematics for here

Comment: Does the LED flash on at startup then go off? That 10k resistor is way too high to drive that LED. It may be that you get a spike go through it when you first start it up, then it'll turn off as 10k is much too high. Also is your capacitor really 1 millifarad? That's quite high too! Try scoping the OUT pin (if it really is a 1mF cap you are using, a DMM will do too as it'll be slow enough to see the transition) and see if the output is going from high to low

Comment: I would have written an answer, but want to clarify these few things first, as it could well be something completely different

Comment: The LED works with the 10k resistor, when I use the 555; and with the 1mF (1000uf) I want to push the cycle length to ~20 seconds; or you have an alternative for this? And yes: it flashes up on startup; does one cycle but then it stays off. But I will try it with a lower resistor value later.

Comment: That LED definitely will not work properly with a 10k resistor..... If you are using 5V LED (a blue one at that) then your drop is around 3V(ish) SO that would give you: 2/10k = 200uA current. I haven't seen an LED working nicely at 200uA before! I think you are just seeing a startup flash. But before you do change the resistor, measure that output and see if it is changing

Comment: Did you ever measure the voltage at THR (threshold) pin? It should rise and fall between 1/3 VCC and 2/3 VCC,

Comment: Can your power supply support enough current/energy to drive the whole 556 circuit? It has to deliver 12 mA (at 5Volts) and with the very low R1 of 330 Ohms, you need additionally 15 mA during discharging period. Try to rise R1 e.g. to minimum 1k.

Comment: @dessi what did you find when you measured the circuit?